Boto3: How to get subdirectories and subdirectories and join files in second level?
I have file path in s3 that look like:
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/a/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/a/file2.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/b/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/b/file2.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/c/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/c/file2.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir3/a/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir3/a/file2.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir4/b/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir4/b/file2.json

I want to combine all files that are in the same directories after level1. So for example files in dir2 should all be combined, dir3 all combined, and dir 4 all combined.
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/a/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/a/file2.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/b/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/b/file2.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/c/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir2/c/file2.json

should all be in: s3://bucket/level1/dir2/new/newfile.json

s3://bucket/level1/dir3/a/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir3/a/file2.json

should all be in: s3://bucket/level1/dir3/new/newfile.json

s3://bucket/level1/dir4/b/file1.json
s3://bucket/level1/dir4/b/file2.json

should all be in: s3://bucket/level1/dir4/new/newfile.json

I am using the code:
import boto3
import os

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
bucket = 'bucket'
prefix = 'level1/'
files = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix = prefix)['Contents']


paths = sorted({os.path.dirname(obj['Key']) for obj in files})

for path in paths:
    #print(path)
    backPath = "/".join(path.split("/")[:-2]) + "/combined_output/"
    print(backPath)
    path_files = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix = path)['Contents']
    path_files = [x['Key'] for x in path_files]
    result=[]
    for key in path_files:
        print(key)
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        content = json.loads(data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8"))
        result.append(content)
    print(len(result))
    fileName = backPath.split("/")[-3]  + '.json'
    uploadKey = backPath + fileName
    print(uploadKey)
    s3.put_object(Bucket= s3_bucket, Key= uploadKey, Body = json.dumps(result,indent = 6))
    #print(len(result))
    print("-----------")

However, when it goes through the loop, it is overwriting stuff in dir2. a gets overwritten by b and then b gets overwritten by c
How can I get the everything after level1 in one directory based on the dir1/dir2/dir3?
